# Print links to all pdfs using bash

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I'm writing bash script that should download html page and from that page extracts all links to the pdf files.

I have to say, that I'm newbie to bash so for now I can only grep all lines that contains `<a href` and afterwards grep these lines that have `pdf` word.

I can barelly use `awk` but i don't know how to write right regex to get only text in `<a href="*.pdf">` where I want to have `*.pdf`.

EDIT: `grep "<a href=\"*.pdf\""` does not find all links to pdfs, how is that possible? For example `<a href="lorem ipsum.pdf">...</a>` is not found.

Comment: You should read a manual about the syntax of regular expressions. `*` (star) and `.` (dot) have special meanings. For your `grep` command try `'<a href=".*\.pdf">'`, instead.

Comment: Something like this? [root@puppet:0 newrelic-infra]# echo $code
<href="abc.pdf">
[root@puppet:0 newrelic-infra]# echo $code|awk 'BEGIN{FS="\""}{print $2}'
abc.pdf
..Once you have grepped the lines containing pdf and href , try piping it to awk 'BEGIN{FS="\""}{print $2}'

Comment: don't use regex, use html parsers

Comment: grep -o will be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this line to the whole html String. Works perfectly for me.

```
grep -io "<a[[:space:]]*href=\"[^\"]\+\.pdf\">" | awk 'BEGIN{FS="\""}{print $2}'
```